# ¿Cómo importo MD Bootstrap, ya que no lo detecta?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, md-bootstrap

Estoy intentando importar una **librería** de `css` y `js` que se llama MD Bootstrap, ya que me llamó mucho la atención algunos diseños que manejan y en especifico necesito uno que es para un `select multiple` pero copio tal cuál el código e importo las **librerías** y no me funciona, me salta un error de tipo

> TypeError: $(...)materialSelect is not a function

Pero se supone que el método es propio de la librería, sí alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradezco.

Dejo el `HTML` donde lo importo

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link REL=StyleSheet HREF="\Jomar\users_control\config\estilos.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Jomar/users_control/images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.9/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.9/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <title>Realizar registro</title>
</head>
```

[Aquí](https://mdbootstrap.com/md-bootstrap-cdn/) muestran cómo importarlo

Y aquí hago el `select multiple` que ofrecen ellos
`HTML`

```
<select class="mdb-select md-form" multiple searchable="Search here..">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your country</option>
                <option value="1">USA</option>
                <option value="2">Germany</option>
                <option value="3">France</option>
                <option value="3">Poland</option>
                <option value="3">Japan</option>
            </select>
```

`JQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.mdb-select').materialSelect();
    });
```

Y esta es la [demo](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/temp/1135703) que ofrecen ellos

Comment: revisaste que los link del CDN estuvieran disponibles?

Comment: Sí, los revisé todos

Comment: En que parte de codigo estas llamando a $('.mdb-select').materialSelect();

Comment: Te dejare la respuesta abajo.

Comment: Está arriba, justo al abrir el `body`

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, si te sirve la puedes marcar en caso que si a otra persona frecuenta el mismo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes no es que estas importando mal la libreria, simplemente que estas usando la versión `free` la cúal te limita a usar ciertos componentes pero para otros debes usar la versión `pro` que es de pago.

Indicado lo anterior, en la documentación de `mdbootstrap` si buscas el componente `Multiselect` te podrás dar cuenta que su uso implica tener una licencia para la versión `pro`, osea debes pagar o comprar esta versión para hacer uso de el.

Dado lo anterior el error que te muestra por consola...

> TypeError: $(...)materialSelect is not a function

Es un error correcto, ya que en las los CDN que se importaron no existe esta función, pero si existe en los CDN de la versión paga.

Espero que te sirva esta respuesta y recuerda de revisar la documentación de lo que estas usando antes de... este es el mejor recurso que tienes (la documentación)

**RECOMENDACIÓN PARA MULTISELECT**

Puedes probar usar [MaterializeCSS](https://materializecss.com/) tiene un buen componente para multiselect y lo mejor es que NO DEPENDE DE JQUERY ! también puedes usar [Material For Web](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/)

Comment: Ya lo veo, tienes toda la razón, gracias

Comment: De nada, edite mi respuesta y te deje unos enlaces de muy buenas librerías que son open source ! (:

Comment: Gracias, el problema es que ya estoy usando bootstrap y materialize lo cambia